# Airfare plane ticket pricing search notification?

Tags: webapp-rec

Does there exist a plane ticket / airfare search and book webapp with the possibility to add a mail trigger, which will send me mail when a certain route gets under a user indicated price?

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This site](http://www.msnbc.msn.com/id/20975800/ns/travel-news/t/best-airfare-alert-listing-sites/) lists a few airfare alert sites.

I have used [Yapta](http://www.Yapta.com) before and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [Hotwire](http://www.hotwire.com/trip-watcher/index.jsp) has a trip watch feature.

> **Be your own travel agent**
>
> Trip Watcher acts as your own personalized travel agent. It gives you
>   better control, value and flexibility when booking trips by allowing
>   you to watch specific itineraries through email alerts.
>
> **Explore more travel choices**
>
> Tell us where you would like to go within a 60-day range you specify.
>   We'll watch ALL those dates for you at once and find your low-priced
>   travel days
>
> **Compare prices at a glance**
>
> View your watched trips and easily compare trips and prices for smooth
>   planning.
>
> **Get started**
>
> Easily add trips from your search results by clicking "Watch this
>   trip." Or sign in to "My Account" and add a new trip.